# Detect when a user presses the space button

Tags: ios, keyboard-events

I currently have my keyboard set so the type is Numbers and Punctuation [so users can type in a hypen symbol]. Does anyone know how to detect if the user presses the space bar so I can automatically set the style to a different keyboard type [in my case letters] so I don't have to build a custom keyboard?

Comment: Is this for a UITextField? Look at the delegate methods.

Comment: see link http://www.appcoda.com/custom-keyboard-tutorial/ and http://www.appdesignvault.com/ios-8-custom-keyboard-extension/

Comment: The keyboards have a globe button that allows the user to change the keyboard to the default defined or rotate among installed keyboards - If you still want to put in the  code to detect if the space bar is pressed the textfield/ textview delegate methods in particular to use is the textView shouldChangeTextinRange   -  ...   - - If you still need the code just ask,

Comment: @aMrAhD_nAleEhS thanks but not thanks, specifically stated I didn't want to create a custom keyboard if possible

Comment: @rmaddy yes it's the text field in the search bar of a search display controller

Comment: @Paulo thanks for your suggestion. I am aware of the globe, but I don't want to create a custom keyboard for this. I will look into shouldChangeText, i'm sure I will need help with the coding if you can provide it. I am a newbie thxs

Comment: Since this is a `UISearchBar`, look at the `UISearchBarDelegate` methods. It has the `...shouldChangeTextInRange...` method you need to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code - I am sure that it will detect if  a space character is coded in - I have not really tested how well the keyboard switch works. You should also try it out without the resignfirstresponder becomefirstresponder code once the code below is working.  Good Luck!  (PS your viewCOntroller needs to be declared as a UITextview or textfield Delegate)

```
    - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:         (NSString *)text_message {
   if ([text_message isEqual:@" "]) {
//     Put your code to change the keyboard then refresh the screen.
       [textView resignFirstResponder];   //close textview or textfield 
       [textView setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
       [textView becomeFirstResponder];  // opens keyboard for textfield or textview
       [self.view setNeedsRefresh];  // refresh view
  //   return NO;  
  }
  return YES;  //go back to editing
}
```